# IllegalStateException when launching application after moved between computers

Tags: java, android, xml, themes

**tl;dr**

These exact files work on one workstation, and not another one.

**What I get (error)**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                  

  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{com.example.erik.recipefriend2/com.example.erik.recipefriend2.MainActivity}: 
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a 
  Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

The error is at line 26, which in my case is this:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**What I have done** As the topic states, I have been moving my Android Studio project from my stationary computer onto my laptop. I have been using Git with Bitbucket to be able to work on both computers. When I pulled the project and tried to run it, I got the error message displayed above. When I zipped the project from my stationary computer and unpacked it and launched it on my laptop, I got the same error. Lastly, I pasted the indivudial files (class files, drawables and xml-files) into a newly created project, but I still get the error.

I am running out of ideas. I have also line for line checked the classes on my stationary computer and compared them to the lines on my laptop, to no avail.

I will include the classes and xmls that I think are involved in this matter.

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.RecipesApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorGreen</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp</item>


</style>


</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.erik.recipefriend2">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.erik.recipefriend2.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.RecipesApp" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addIngredient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:backgroundTint="#91FF93"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:onClick="goToAdd"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/searchRecipe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#91FF93"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:onClick="goToSearch"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.erik.recipefriend2;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
       actionBar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
       actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
       actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addIngredient);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
       MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
       menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   @Override
      protected boolean onPrepareOptionsPanel(View view, Menu menu) {
      if (menu != null) {
        if (menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")) {
            try {
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onMenuOpened...unable to set icons for overflow menu", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsPanel(view, menu);
   }
   public void goToAdd(View view){

   }
   public void goToSearch(){

   }


}
```

What can the problem be? Also, if more files are needed, I will be happy to display them as well.

Comment: how are you launching it from the new machine, can you try to launch everything from the same device for me and see if its different on both ? also post your gradle  files

Comment: Where do you define `AppTheme.NoActionBar`?

Comment: On the machine that is working, I'm launching from the built in emulator, Nexus 4 I think. On the machine that is not working, I have Genymotion installed, which I use for launching.

I do not know for the AppTheme.NoActionBar is defined, because it came with the "project model" I used (built-in in Android Studio). 

Also, I will update the first post with the gradle files.

Comment: Apparently, that notation "AppTheme.NoActionBar must have been added by mistake. It should just be AppTheme, and then it works.

However, I did find out that when I launch it in Genymotion, the overflow icon does not show up as it should. When I launch it with the built-in Nexus 4 emulator, it does. I do not know why this is.

Tynn, if you want to post your suggestion as an answer, I would be happy to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On you're activity you define `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` while you don't define `AppTheme.NoActionBar` anywhere in your styles. It's confusing that this compiles, but would explain why there's an error.

Comment: This solved it. However, as you said, it is strange that this works fine on my other workstation. Anyway, thanks.